# linq GroupBy List<Class> into new List<Class>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Class called Person

```
class Person() {
 string Name;
 string SSN;
}
```

as well as a List That Contains many common instances of the Person class that are duplicates. For Example

```
   Person.Name = "John";
   Person.SSN = "123456789";
   Person.Name = "John";
   Person.SSN = "123456789";
   Person.Name = "John";
   Person.SSN = "123456789";
   Person.Name = "John";
   Person.SSN = "123456789";
   Person.Name = "John";
   Person.SSN = "123456789";
```

I am trying to figure the syntax out for a Linq statement to just take one of the class objects in the List when common and add it to a new list.

```
List<Person> newPerson = new List<Person>();

newPerson.AddRange(person.GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x.SSN).Select(grp => grp.ToList().First()).ToList());
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your intent - *the syntax out for a Linq statement to just take one of the class objects in the List when common*? I have read it several times and still don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq distinct or group by multiple properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582391/linq-distinct-or-group-by-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GroupBy` syntax is slightly off, and you don't need all of those `ToList` calls:

```
newPerson.AddRange(person.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name, x.SSN})
                         .Select(grp => grp.First()));
```

or just

```
newPerson = person.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name, x.SSN})
                  .Select(grp => grp.First())
                  .ToList();
```

since you're starting with an empty list anyways.

**Detailed explanation**

Your original syntax:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x.SSN)
```

compiles becasue there's an [overload for `GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) that takes a lambda for the key selector and another lambda for the result selector.  It essentially grouped your collection by `Name` but returned a collection of strings (extracting the `SSN` property)

What you want to do is to create an anonymous type representing your compound key:

```
.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name, x.SSN})
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be to implement equality (either in `Person` directly, or via an `IEqualityComparer<Person>`) and then do a `Distinct`. E.g.

```
class Person : IEquatable<Person> {
    // these should be properties, e.g. public string Name { get; set; }
    string Name;
    string SSN;
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        // XOR is not the best generally, but can work for something like this
        return Name.GetHashCode() ^ SSN.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other) {
        return Equals(other as Person);
    }
    public bool Equals(Person other) {
        return other != null && this.Name == other.Name && this.SSN == other.SSN;
    }
}


var newPerson = person.Distinct().ToList();
```