# Select distinct rows in c# datatable on single column but return all columns

Tags: c#

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
dt= view.ToTable(true, "id");
```

If i have 2 columns "id" and "name" i need to get the distinct "id" but not the distinct "name" but i need to keep the column "name" in my datatable what shall i do?

Answer (score 3):

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);
```

If i have 2 columns "id" and "name" i need to get the distinct "id" but not the distinct "name" but i need to keep the column "name" in my datatable what shall i do?

OK, then i need grouping, not distinct.I could do it with Linq to DataSet: `table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("id")).Select(group =>group.First()).CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: but its returning only one row :(

Comment: @HimanshuSuthar which one? and which way you are using distinct or grouping?

Comment: there should 3 distinct rows after group by operations, but it returns only first.

Comment: Check this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582391/linq-distinct-or-group-by-multiple-properties).